# 1 - Combinatorics - High School Level Olympiad Problem

Tags: combinatorics

There are five cards labeled $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ respectively and there are five boxes labeled $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ respectively. A card is put into each box randomly. Find the number of ways in which exactly $2$ cards have labels matching the labels on the box.

What I did,
$$C(5,2)(1/5)^2(4/5)^3 = 640/3125$$
Since $n(E)=5^5=3125, n(a)=640$.

The number of ways is 640?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I just edited the post and showed my solution :)

Comment: There are only 5!=120 ways of putting the cards into the boxes. The correct answer is 20.

Comment: There are $C(5,2)$ ways to select two $2$ cards, which we will say go in their corresponding boxes. Then, there is only $2$ ways we can order the last $3$ such that they do not go in their corresponding boxes. This means the answer is $2 C(5,2) = 20$

Comment: @Janjan: My answer involved selecting all $5$ cards. I initially selected $2$ cards at random and set them aside, saying "these are the cards which will go in their matching boxes." There are $C(5,2)$ ways to select these $2$ cards. Then I forced the other $3$ to go in *other* boxes than their own. This ensures that exactly $2$ were placed in the right boxes.

Comment: I think in the problem, it is possible that there can be more than $1$ cards in a box. Because according to what @Janjan says, size of the sample space is $3125$.

Comment: Then you can choose $2$ cards with $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ and for the remaining $3$ cards, there are $4^3 = 64$ options. So the answer $640$ seems correct to me.

Comment: Thank you guys for making it clearer for me :)

Comment: You choose 2 of them to be placed in their right boxes in $\binom 52=10$ ways and then _derange_ (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html)) the rest in $D_3=3!(1-1+1/2-1/6)=3-1=2$ ways, hence a total of $10\times 2=20$ ways.